# Is possible to read/write ros topic from Java?

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to write a (initially) simple Java program that writes messages to a ros topic and reads messages from another topic.
Is this possible?

Thank you!

Andrea Luzzana

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44844/is-possible-to-read/write-ros-topic-from-java?/) by [Andrea Luzzana](https://answers.ros.org/users/3288/andrea-luzzana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a read here -

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. Why not? All you need is one subscriber and one publisher.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1